# How to remove or modify a div tag using css when the div tag is not associated with any class or id

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following html code and this is part of the html

```
<div class="template-page-wrapper">
  <div class="templemo-content-wrapper">
    <div class="templatemo-content">
      <div class="templatemo-panels">
          <div id="dPopupBG" class="popup_BG"></div>
          <div style="height:100px;"><div>
          <div id="MainContent" class="msg" style="display: none;">  
          <div class="error display" style="display:none"><span></span></div>
          <div id="MainDocContent" class="flex"> 
             (and Here page content having more html details)
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a more space between the header line and the MainDocContent. When I focus using inspect on the empty space then the inspect element is highlighted to below tag

```
  <div style="height:100px;"><div>
```

I tried the below css to adjust the height in the css file but the height is not getting modified

```
#dPopupBG+div{height:80px}
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Your css is invalid. `{height=80px} `  should be `{height:80px} `

Comment: Also, if you want to get the selector you can use developer tools, right-click on the relevant div and click Copy->Copy Selector.

Comment: @LeeTaylor : I have given in the css  file as height:80px only , here typing mistake . Sorry for the typo here.

Comment: what you can do is remove that `div` element which is causing the problem and instead use `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` of `80px` on `#dPopupBG`

Comment: @KunalTanwar : This height div element is showing when viewed through F12 developer tools only and it is not associated with any class or id to overwrite the css. Hence not knowing to fix this height issue in the application.

Comment: This seems to be a problem that should be solved on the back-end; if that element exists purely to insert space to the design it should be removed and the space applied using either `padding` or `margin` (whichever you feel is more appropriate). The answers suggest using `!important` to override the inline styles - which is valid - but any solution that requires `!important` be used implies a bad design choice elsewhere; and this is definitely the result of a bad design choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you only can override an inline property by adding `!important`

```css
#example+div{
  height:80px;
  background-color:orange!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
<div style="background-color:black;"><div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , I tried as  #dPopupBG+div{height:80px !important}  and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Override inline style is by using *!important* keyword With the CSS rule.

```css
#dPopupBG + div
{
height:80px!important;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-page-wrapper">
  <div class="templemo-content-wrapper">
    <div class="templatemo-content">
      <div class="templatemo-panels">
          <div id="dPopupBG" class="popup_BG"></div>
          <div style="height:100px;"><div>
          <div id="MainContent" class="msg" style="display: none;">  
          <div class="error display" style="display:none"><span></span></div>
          <div id="MainDocContent" class="flex"> 
             (and Here page content having more html details)
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/* a simple set of rules to remove default margin and padding
   from elements, and to size elements with an algorithm that
   includes padding and border sizes in the defined width: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  /* to visualise the HTML structure: */ 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* to center the elements in the inline axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* to apply some spacing around the contents/descendants
     of an element: */
  padding: 0.5em;
  /* to show the parent-child hierarchy for visualisation: */
  width: 90%;
}

/* selects all <div> elements with a class attribue,
   and styles the ::before pseudo-element: */
div[class]::before {
  /* shows the contents of that attribute in the
     ::before pseuedo element; again for visualisation: */
  content: attr(class);
}

/* this selects all <div> elements with a "style" attribute
   with an attribute-value that includes the string 
   "height:100px", or "height: 100px" (note the white-space):*/
div[style*="height:100px"],
div[style*="height: 100px"]{
  /* purely to visualise the element if it's not successfully
     hidden: */
  background-color: red;
  /* "hiding" the element by setting its display to "none";
     this avoids having to use "!important" to override the
     height (which may have other consequences), but is fragile
     as it's based on a predetermined/known "height" property-value: */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-page-wrapper">
  <div class="templemo-content-wrapper">
    <div class="templatemo-content">
      <div class="templatemo-panels">
        <div id="dPopupBG" class="popup_BG"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;">
          <div>
            <div id="MainContent" class="msg" style="display: none;">
              <div class="error display" style="display:none"><span></span></div>
              <div id="MainDocContent" class="flex">
                (and Here page content having more html details)
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qp5t7w3n/).

References:

- [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).
- [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).